# Equality of topologies in the spaces of section of a vector bundle

Tags: vector-bundles, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

In this notes [Geometric Wave Equations](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4706) by [Stefan Waldmann](https://mathoverflow.net/users/12482/stefan-waldmann)  at page 7 he has
Let $E \longrightarrow M$ be a vector bundle of rank $N$.  For a chart $(U, \psi)$ we consider a compact subset $K \subseteq U$ together with a basis  sections $e_{\alpha} \in \Gamma^{\infty}\left(\left.\boldsymbol{E}\right|_{\boldsymbol{U}}\right)$ such that for a section $s$ we have
$$
\left.s\right|_{U}=s^{\alpha} e_{\alpha}
$$
We define the seminorms
$$
\mathrm{p}_{U, \psi, K, \ell,\left\{e_{\alpha}\right\}}(s)=\sup _{\substack{x \in K \\|I| \leq \ell \\ \alpha=1, \ldots, N}}\left|\frac{\partial^{|I|} s^{\alpha}}{\partial x^{I}}(x)\right|
$$

then he has

for every compact subset $K \subseteq M$ we consider another seminorm
$$
\mathrm{p}_{K, \ell}(s)=\sup _{p \in K}\left\|\left.\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell} s\right|_p\right\|_h,
$$
where $\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell}$ is the symmetrized covariant derivative

The goal here is to proof that
$$
\mathrm{p}_{U, x, K, \ell,\left\{e_\alpha\right\}}(s) \leq c \max _{\ell^{\prime} \leq \ell} \mathrm{p}_{K, \ell^{\prime}}(s)\tag 0
$$
to do that he uses the fact that
$$
\left.\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell} s\right|_U=\mathrm{d} x^{i_1} \vee \cdots \vee \mathrm{d} x^{i_{\ell}} \otimes e_\alpha \frac{\partial^{\ell} s^\alpha}{\partial x^{i_1} \cdots \partial x^{x_{\ell}}}+\text { (lower order terms). }
\tag{**}$$

his argument at page 11 is

given a $\mathrm{p}_{U, \psi, K, \ell,\left\{e_\alpha\right\}}$ we see from $(* *)$ that we can estimate the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^{|J|} s_s^\alpha}{\partial x^J}$ with $|J| \leq \ell$ by norm of $\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell} s$ and norms of partial derivatives $\frac{\partial^{\mid J^{\prime}} \mid s^\alpha}{\partial x^{J^{\prime}}}$ for $\left|J^{\prime}\right|<\ell$.

I am not seeing why his argument is true.

how can we proof eq $(0)$  for  $l=1$
where  have $$\left.\left(\mathrm{D}^E\right)^{\ell} s\right|_U =\left[\partial_i s^a+\left(\Gamma_E\right)_{i b}^a s^b\right] d x^i \otimes e_a \tag 1$$?

Comment: For me the question hinges on the meaning of the verb "desambarace", which is not an English verb, so I don't understand the question. Google translate (any language) doesn't help.

Comment: I think there are still some words missing from the question to make its meaning clear, specifically in your supposed counter example around "... is $\alpha=m$ then ..." (is what?). Overall, the length of the question I think obscures a quite simple core observation: there is a triangular linear transformation back and forth between the partial coordinate derivatives of the components of $s$ and between the components $(\mathrm{D}^E)^\ell s$ up to the same order, with smooth (hence bounded on any compact set) coefficients. I don't see what's so complicated about that.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine can you clarify your comment with an answer

Comment: I think that the statement is not true as stated, as the right hand side of (0) takes into account lower order as well (in particular constant terms), while the left hand side does not. Hence if the Christoffel symbols vanish, the left hand side is zero on constant functions, but the right hand side.

Comment: Moreover, the right hand side of (0) is still ill-defined because there is a maximum over $n$ taken, but $U_n$ etc. are not defined.

Comment: I will edit my question

Comment: Your edits have not taken into account the essence of what Matthias Ludewig remarked on. Your (0) is still false as written, e.g., for constant $s$.

Comment: @ 
Igor Khavkine I edited my question again

Comment: Now you can easily write an answer to your own question after noting that $(**)$ is invertible between the components of $(\mathrm{D})^{\le \ell} s^\alpha$ and $\partial^{\le \ell} s^\alpha$, and that (for fixed $K$) the $c$ in (0) comes down to computing an [induced matrix norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Matrix_norms_induced_by_vector_norms) of the inverse transformation in $(**)$.